# I can't install rosbridge_suite

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosbridge-server, rosbridge-suite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I try installing [rosbridge_suite](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbridge_suite) on ubuntu 18.04 with melodic.

I tried

- sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-server
- sudo apt install ros-indigo-rosbridge-server
- sudo apt install ros-melodic-rosbridge-server

and also

- sudo apt install ros-kinetic-rosbridge-suite
- sudo apt install ros-indigo-rosbridge-suite
- sudo apt install ros-melodic-rosbridge-suite

I can't get it. Always the message "Unable to locate package ros--rosbridge-suite" or "Unable to locate package ros--rosbridge-server".

What I do wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294403/i-can%27t-install-rosbridge_suite/) by [Mumie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31881/mumie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What I do wrong?

Nothing really, other than not checking whether `rosbridge_suite` is actually released into ROS Melodic.

As you can see both on the wiki page that you link us to (note how the version selector right under the package name at the top of the page doesn't have a button for `melodic`), as well as on [status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=rosbridge](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=rosbridge), the package(s) simply hasn't (haven't) been released yet for Melodic.

So `apt` telling you it can't find the package is actually correct.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mumie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31881/mumie/) on 2018-06-18**:
I read that but thought I can still install a older version?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-18**:
No, you cannot install `kinetic` or `indigo` packages on Ubuntu Bionic, as those ROS versions are simply not supported on Bionic.

**Comment by [Mumie](https://answers.ros.org/users/31881/mumie/) on 2018-06-18**:
Thank you very much. I tried to additionally install the package in a ROS Melodic docker file. But than I go with a ROS Kinetic docker file.